# Creating Local Group and Adding A User To The Group

Tags: powershell, iis-7, powershell-1.0

I have a PowerShell script that builds IIS sites and configures settings. Most of it works as expected except for a function to either add a domain user to a specific local group or if the group is not there to create the group than add the user. I get this error when adding to the group:

> Exception calling "add" with "1" argument(s): "A member could not be added to or removed from the local group because the member does not exist.

I have PowerShell v1.0 so I do not have access to the Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts module so using `Add-LocalGroupMember` and `New-LocalGroup` are not an option.

```
function addEventLogWriter($appPoolUser) {
    $user = $appPoolUser
    $group = "Event Log Writers"
    $description = "Members of this group can write event logs from local machine" 

    #try{
    $groupObj =[ADSI]"WinNT://./$group,group" 
    $membersObj = @($groupObj.psbase.Invoke("Members")) 
    $members = ($membersObj | foreach {
        $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
    })

    Write-Output "Adding Service Account To Event Log Writers..."
    if ($members -contains $user) {
        Write-Host "$user already exists in the group $group..."
    } else {
        $groupObj.add("WinNT://./$user,user")
        Write-Output "$user added to $group"
    }
}
```

At the moment the group 'Event Log Writers' has been created but in the case it is not (ie: new server builds etc..), I would like my function check to make sure the group is there, if not, create the group than add the user.

Comment: What is the format of your user? e.g. `contoso\jsmith`?

Comment: The format is ```Domain\User```. I have an another function that uses 'Get-Credential' earlier as this service account is used for folder permissions as well as other IIS Settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because ADSI requires a slash instead of a backslash like a typical username.

Also, how the group membership returns, in this case, it drops the domain name, so we have to split out the username when seeing if it exists.

So if your `$appPoolUser` is a credential object with the full username:

```
function addEventLogWriter($appPoolUser) {
    $AdsiUsername = $appPoolUser.replace('\','/')
    $user = $appPoolUser.Split('\')[1]

    $group = "Event Log Writers"
    $description = "Members of this group can write event logs from local machine" 

    #try{
    $groupObj =[ADSI]"WinNT://./$group,group" 
    $membersObj = @($groupObj.psbase.Invoke("Members")) 
    $members = ($membersObj | foreach {
        $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
    })

    Write-Output "Adding Service Account To Event Log Writers..."
    if ($members -contains $user) {
        Write-Host "$user already exists in the group $group..."
    } else {
        $groupObj.add("WinNT://./$AdsiUsername,user")
        Write-Output "$user added to $group"
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but now its throwing a **you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression** error. I think it is with these two variables `$AdsiUsername = $appPoolUser.UserName.replace('\','/')
    $user = $appPoolUser.UserName.Split('\')[1]`   I did a `write-host "$appPoolUser"` and it returned the domain account as expected.

Comment: @sec_eng1 is probably calling the function with a string `domain\username` as parameter, but it expects a credential object. If a string is the preferred way for the OP, remove the `.UserName` from the lines `$appPoolUser.UserName.replace('\','/')` and `$appPoolUser.UserName.Split('\')[1]`

Comment: @sec_eng1, as @Theo was saying, I was thinking that the `$appPoolUser` was coming in as a `Credential` object. So I edited the question to remove the `.Username`

Comment: That worked that time. It did come in as a string as I had it defined as such in the beginning `[string]$appPoolUser = $null`. I may change it but for now it works. Thanks for the help!